# wildcard certificate clientAuth=true

Tags: ssl, certificate, tomcat8

I'm having issues with a web service I'm trying to host.

Running on CentOS 6.5 amd64 / linux x86_64, Tomcat 8.0.9, Java 1.7.0_60, CXF 3.0.

When I setup my Connector as such:

```
<Connector port="443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true" scheme="https" secure="true"
keystoreFile="${catalina.base}/conf/server.jks"
keyAlias="salesproxy.<domain>.com"
keystorePass="<password>"
clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" />
```

I can pull the WSDL via HTTPS and view the certificate and all is good.

But, if I set clientAuth="true" and add truststoreFile, truststoreType and truststorePass attributes to the Connector, I can't even access the WSDL via HTTPS.  I receive a "Error code: ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR" message from Chrome.

In my log with javax.net.debug=ssl set, below are the last few lines:

```
*** ServerHelloDone
http-nio-443-exec-4, WRITE: SSLv3 Handshake, length = 13028
http-nio-443-exec-6, READ: SSLv3 Alert, length = 2
http-nio-443-exec-6, RECV SSLv3 ALERT:  warning, no_certificate
SSL -- handshake alert:  no_certificate
http-nio-443-exec-6, fatal error: 80: problem unwrapping net record
javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: handshake alert: no_certificate
%% Invalidated:  [Session-67, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA]
http-nio-443-exec-6, SEND SSLv3 ALERT:  fatal, description = internal_error
http-nio-443-exec-6, WRITE: SSLv3 Alert, length = 2
http-nio-443-exec-6, called closeOutbound()
http-nio-443-exec-6, closeOutboundInternal()
```

In Chrome and Windows 8 certmgr, I've installed the Client Cert in every place that makes any sense to me without change in behavior.  One point to note is that the server is using a GoDaddy wildcard SSL certificate.  I've used wildcard certs before, but not with 2-way SSL auth.

Any help/suggestions/recommendations would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Did you put the client cert in the personal or alike store on the chrome client? I believe windows certmgr has a way to specify that this is a personal cert.

Comment: Yes, I tried personal, Trusted Root, Trusted Intermediate and combinations of the above.

Comment: Is your client cert designated to be used for client auth?http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/1438/what-is-the-difference-between-an-x-509-client-certificate-and-a-normal-ssl-ce

Comment: Honestly, I'm not sure.  SalesForce.com generated the Certificate.  It is self-signed by SFDC.  I'll read that post and comment again.

Comment: Good article. So when I look at the certificate in certmgr, the intended purposes are: All issuance policies & All application policies.  I'm not sure, but that sounds like client authentication would be included in those.

Comment: Another update, I can get the a client cert to pass via curl, as long as I generate the client cert and pass the private key as well.  The problem with SFDC is that I cannot get the private key from them, ever.  So my question now becomes: Is the private key needed?  I thought the client authentication was simply passing a known certificate from the client to the server.  Is there more?  I'm not doing digital signatures or digests.

Comment: The PK is not required by the server. Question is the diff in the cert you generated Versus the SF one. You might wanna print the certificate- use Open SSL. Check Enhanced key usage at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kaushal/archive/2012/02/18/client-certificates-v-s-server-certificates.aspx